# how to overlay image on image on preview images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overlay

I Found preview image after upload

From

http://saravani.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/preview-of-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded/

I tested it, and success.

and then I wanna overlay PREVIEW TEXT Image

[image]

if upload above image.

and overlaying bottom image

[image]

and i waana this image using background repeat attributes

[image]

Comment: So... Have you tried anything?  What are you getting stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overlay images like this:

```css
#img1 {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQfkx.jpg) repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div id="img1"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></div>
```

Comment: if using this code, upload image setting div's background_image?

Comment: Using background image for content doesn't allow preview box to be resized according to image size/aspect ratio, does it? My 2 cents: http://jsfiddle.net/g24m0ymq/10/